# How can I read this string if it has " and ' ? Python

Tags: python, html, string, quote

I have this string that is basically some html

```
<acronym class="non-experimental-qualifier" title="Indicates that the information given is not based on experimental findings." onclick="dialog('non_experimental_qualifiers'); Event.stop(event || window.event); return false" onmousedown="Event.stop(event || window.event);">By similarity</acronym>. <a class="attribution" href="http://hamap.expasy.org/unirule/
```

is there anyway i can read it as a string in python . . . usually it only has one type of ' or " so i can just use the other to string it but . . . this has both

how can i turn this into a string ? like:

```
html = '<acronym class="non-experimental-qualifier" title="Indicates that the information given is not based on experimental findings." onclick="dialog('non_experimental_qualifiers'); Event.stop(event || window.event); return false" onmousedown="Event.stop(event || window.event);">By similarity</acronym>. <a class="attribution" href="http://hamap.expasy.org/unirule/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [triple-quoted string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
html = '''<acronym class="non-experimental-qualifier" title="Indicates that the information given is not based on experimental findings." onclick="dialog('non_experimental_qualifiers'); Event.stop(event || window.event); return false" onmousedown="Event.stop(event || window.event);">By similarity</acronym>. <a class="attribution" href="http://hamap.expasy.org/unirule/'''
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> mystr = '''It's a "string"'''
>>> mystr
'It\'s a "string"'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape quotes with `\'` and `\"`, or you can use triple quotes:

```
example1 = 'She\'s fond of saying "Hello"'
example2 = "She's fond of saying \"Hello\""
example3 = '''She's fond of saying "Hello"'''
example4 = """She's fond of saying "Hello\""""
```

Be careful with the closing `"` at the end in the triple-quoted string; it has to be escaped still to not count for the last 3 closing quotes.

Demo:

```
>>> example1 = 'She\'s fond of saying "Hello"'
>>> example2 = "She's fond of saying \"Hello\""
>>> example3 = '''She's fond of saying "Hello"'''
>>> example4 = """She's fond of saying "Hello\""""
>>> example1 == example2 == example3 == example4
True
```

In addition, newlines are permitted and preserved in a triple-quoted string, making for a very readable literal HTML value:

```
html = '''\
<acronym class="non-experimental-qualifier" 
         title="Indicates that the information given is not based on experimental findings." 
         onclick="dialog('non_experimental_qualifiers'); Event.stop(event || window.event); return false" 
         onmousedown="Event.stop(event || window.event);">By similarity</acronym>. 
    <a class="attribution" href="http://hamap.expasy.org/unirule/'
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I am confused - to read the string from an external object you don't need to do anything.  Python has batteries included and will handle the quotation marks.  I took your string and saved it in a file and then read it using open().read()

```
>>>mystring = open('c:\\mytest.txt').read()

>>>mystring
'<acronym class="non-experimental-qualifier" title="Indicates that the information given is not based on experimental findings." onclick="dialog(\'non_experimental_qualifiers\'); Event.stop(event || window.event); return false" onmousedown="Event.stop(event || window.event);">By similarity</acronym>. <a class="attribution" href="http://hamap.expasy.org/unirule/'
```

So my question is, do you mean read or are you trying to construct a string like the one above?